# post array of objects that contains image data as multipart through retrofit in android

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, multipartform-data

I have to post some data from android in this form

```
[
   {
    "title": "song's title",
    "artists": "artist1, artist2,....",
    "album": "album name",
    "genre": "genre name",
    "added_at": "datetime etc",
    "counter": x (int value i.e. 3),
    "cover_art": "image data"(File)
   },
   {
    "title": "song's title",
    "artists": "artist1, artist2,....",
    "album": "album name",
    "genre": "genre name",
    "added_at": "datetime etc",
    "counter": x (int value i.e. 3),
    "cover_art": "image data"(File)
   },
   .......and so on.
]
```

How can i post this from retrofit. From what i know is that one can upload images as Multipart in retrofit but here i have json array which contains Image data. 
Please help , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I did this - i created a class with these fields -

```
public class PostServerSongDM {

String title , artists , album , genre, added_at;
long counter;
byte[] cover_art;

public PostServerSongDM(String t , String ar , String al , String ge,     String addat , long cou , String path){

    title = t;
    artists = ar;
    album = al;
    genre = ge;
    added_at = addat;

    counter = cou;


    File image = new File(path.substring(7));
    int size = (int) image.length();
    cover_art = new byte[size];
    try {
        BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(image));
        buf.read(cover_art, 0, cover_art.length);
        buf.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and then created a **Retofit** interface like this -

```
public interface PostSongList {

@POST("your api")
Call<SampleResponse> request(@Body ArrayList<PostServerSongDM> list);

}
```

and with this , i was able to post a request to server with exact json data format which is given in question.

P.S - I don't know if this was an obvious solution or not but i couldn't figure this out before and now i did.